# PFSense: Opt port able to get to my LAN port / internet

Tags: vlan, pfsense

I am trying to setup a disruption between 2 networks one that is coming from the LAN port and one with a different SUBNET from the other (OPT) port.

My LAN is not getting blocked from the OPT subnet and it's also able to access the firewall. I am an unexperienced noob so I do not know what I am doing wrong.

If someone could help me out I'd highly appreciate that!

[image]
[image]
[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJf7L.png)
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full configuration (the text configuration).

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to setup a disruption between 2 networks one that is coming from the LAN port and one with a different SUBNET from the other (OPT) port.

Simply add a firewall rules 'drop from interface LAN with any source address to interface OPT with any destination address' for each IPv4 and IPv6, and drag the rule all the way to the top.

If you also don't want the reverse direction, add another two rules with LAN and OPT reversed.

Comment: That the thing, I've tried doing that but it refuses my orders 

Comment: Please state exactly what you've tried (add it to your question) and what error message you've got.

Comment: Ah it works now, I previously had only IPV4 as protocol and not both.. Works now anyway thanks!

Comment: @BartMolk Then you should make that an answer and accept it, so your question doesn't keep popping up forever.